# how to read closure properties in browser console using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console, closures

How to read closure properties in browser console using jquery?

Please see screenshot of closure.. how to print "canClick" value in console?

[image]

Comment: This is a screenshot of what? I am not familiar with such tree view (with "local" and "closure"), how did you make this appear? Also can you post some code?

Comment: Hi Hamsteriffic, This is screenshot from chrome dev console.